How to increase nested TableView's Height in Swift iOS?
I have the main TableView which cell contains another TableView and this TableView's cell also contains another TableView.
This is the response I'm getting from the backend:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "my first collection",
      "sub_collections": [],
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 49,
          "productName": "Collection's tag",
          "pairPermission": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "userId": 2,
              "productTagId": 49,
              "collectionId": 3,
              "image": "media/items/images-76626714744276.png",
              "order": null,
              "createdAt": "2024-07-05T04:30:12.000Z",
              "updatedAt": "2024-07-05T04:30:12.000Z",
              "isAccess": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "my second collection",
      "sub_collections": [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "my sub collection1",
          "tags": [
            {
              "id": 58,
              "productName": "MILLA 12212",
              "pairPermission": 1,
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": 22,
                  "userId": 2,
                  "productTagId": 58,
                  "collectionId": 8,
                  "image": "media/items/images-18956357544315.png",
                  "order": null,
                  "createdAt": "2024-07-09T10:24:25.000Z",
                  "updatedAt": "2024-07-09T10:24:25.000Z",
                  "isAccess": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "my sub collection",
      "sub_collections": [],
      "tags": []
    }
  ]
}

I want to achieve exactly like this:

Below is the main TableView:
// MARK: - TableViewDelegate and DataSource
extension ProductAccessSettingScreen: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.productAccessArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductAccessTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductAccessTableViewCell {
            let productAccess = self.productAccessArray[indexPath.row]
            
            cell.collectionNameLabel.text = productAccess.name
            cell.arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: productAccess.isSelected ?? false ? "downArrow_ic" : "upArrow_ic")
            cell.bottomLineView.isHidden = (indexPath.row == self.productAccessArray.count - 1) ? false : true
            cell.subCollectionsArray = []
            cell.tagListArray = []
            
            if productAccess.subCollections?.count != 0 {
                cell.subCollectionsArray = productAccess.subCollections ?? []
            } else {
                cell.tagListArray = productAccess.tags ?? []
            }
            cell.listingTableView.reloadData()
            cell.listingTableView.isHidden = !(productAccess.isSelected ?? false)
            
            cell.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.listingTableView.contentSize.height
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.productAccessArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = !(self.productAccessArray[indexPath.row].isSelected ?? false)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.productAccessTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
}

Below is the Main TableView's cell:
class ProductAccessTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - Outlets
    //UIView
    @IBOutlet weak var labelView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLineView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLineView: UIView!
    
    //UITableView
    @IBOutlet weak var listingTableView: UITableView!
    
    //UIImageView
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImageView: UIImageView!
    
    //UILabel
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    //NSLayoutConstraint
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    var subCollectionsArray = [SubCollectionsListData]()
    var tagListArray = [ProductTagsDataInCollectionWise]()
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialDetails()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    func initialDetails() {
        self.listingTableView.delegate = self
        self.listingTableView.dataSource = self
        self.listingTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductAccessSubTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductAccessSubTableViewCell")
        self.listingTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OnlyTagTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OnlyTagTableViewCell")
    }
    
}

// MARK: - TableView Delegate and DataSource
extension ProductAccessTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if subCollectionsArray.count == 0 {
            return tagListArray.count
        }
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if subCollectionsArray.count != 0 {
            return self.subCollectionsArray.count
        } else {
            return self.tagListArray[section].items?.count ?? 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if subCollectionsArray.count != 0 {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductAccessSubTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductAccessSubTableViewCell {
                cell.subCollectionNameLabel.text = self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].name
                cell.arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].isSelected ?? false ? "downArrow_ic" : "upArrow_ic")
                cell.tagListArray = []
                cell.tagListArray = self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].tags ?? []
                cell.listingTableView.reloadData()
                cell.listingTableView.isHidden = !(self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].isSelected ?? false)
                
                cell.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.listingTableView.contentSize.height
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                
                return cell
            }
        } else {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OnlyTagTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? OnlyTagTableViewCell {
                let tagNamesArray = self.tagListArray.map({ $0.productName })
                cell.nameLabel.text = tagNamesArray[indexPath.section]
                cell.cellView.backgroundColor = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9019607843, green: 0.8980392157, blue: 0.8901960784, alpha: 1) : .clear
                cell.cellView.borderWidth = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? 0 : 0.42
                cell.cellView.borderColor = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? .clear : #colorLiteral(red: 0.137254902, green: 0.1215686275, blue: 0.1254901961, alpha: 1)
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.subCollectionsArray.count != 0 {
            self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = !(self.subCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].isSelected ?? false)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.listingTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

Below is the Sub TableView's Cell:
class ProductAccessSubTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - Outlets
    //UIView
    @IBOutlet weak var labelView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLineView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLineView: UIView!
    
    //UITableView
    @IBOutlet weak var listingTableView: UITableView!
    
    //UIImageView
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImageView: UIImageView!
    
    //UILabel
    @IBOutlet weak var subCollectionNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    //NSLayoutConstraint
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    var tagListArray = [ProductTagsDataInCollectionWise]()
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialDetails()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    func initialDetails() {
        self.listingTableView.delegate = self
        self.listingTableView.dataSource = self
        self.listingTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OnlyTagTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OnlyTagTableViewCell")
    }
    
}

// MARK: - TableView Delegate and DataSource
extension ProductAccessSubTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.tagListArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tagListArray[section].items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OnlyTagTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? OnlyTagTableViewCell {
            let tagNamesArray = self.tagListArray.map({ $0.productName })
            cell.nameLabel.text = tagNamesArray[indexPath.section]
            cell.cellView.backgroundColor = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9019607843, green: 0.8980392157, blue: 0.8901960784, alpha: 1) : .clear
            cell.cellView.borderWidth = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? 0 : 0.42
            cell.cellView.borderColor = self.tagListArray[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].isAccess ?? false ? .clear : #colorLiteral(red: 0.137254902, green: 0.1215686275, blue: 0.1254901961, alpha: 1)
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
}

I have been going through so many solutions but haven't found any solution yet from the past two days. If someone could guide me I would be very grateful.
By clicking on "my sub collection1", I'm not able to show "items" count.


